# Issue Excel HLOOKUP

Tags: excel

I am having an issue in [excel-2010](/questions/tagged/excel-2010) that I'm hoping you can help me with.
I am trying to do a `HLOOKUP` comparing a range of values against a separate range of values and if any of the values in the first range are found in the second range then return the second row of the second range.

My `HLOOKUP` will work perfectly if I only search for one value against a range of values but I need to search for a range against a range as the names may change.

`=HLOOKUP(Sheet1!B3,'Sheet2'!H2:I3,2,FALSE)`
This works perfectly as I am only comparing one value, but ideally instead of `'Sheet1!B3'` I'd like to have a range here - I named a range Test and tried this but it didn't work - I was only returned `#VALUE!`

`=HLOOKUP(Test,'Sheet2'!H2:I3,2,FALSE)`

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have data in the following format:

```
         --A---B---C---D---E-   
Key    1| dog cat egg nut erg
Value  2|  q   r   s   t   u
```

hlookup allows you to only do 1 lookup at a time, not a range of lookups. (1 input, 1 output)

`=hlookup("egg", A1:E2, 2, FALSE)` returns `s`

If you have a list of values you want to look up, you'll need to make multiple hlookup calls.

For example:

```
LookupKey LookupResult LookupEquation
  dog         q        =hlookup("dog", A1:E2, 2, FALSE)
  bird        #N/A     =hlookup("bird", A1:E2, 2, FALSE)
  fish        #N/A     =hlookup("fish", A1:E2, 2, FALSE)
  rat         #N/A     =hlookup("rat", A1:E2, 2, FALSE)
  egg         s        =hlookup("egg", A1:E2, 2, FALSE)
```

If you are trying to get the first non-#N/A result from a list, try `=iferror(hlookup("egg", A1:E2, 2, FALSE),iferror(hlookup("bird", A1:E2, 2, FALSE),...))`

If you want something that can accept a key range, you'll need to write a VBA-macro.

Answer (score 0):

A formula in Excel can only return a value in the cell it is entered in.
Therefore, you cannot enter a single formula that will return values over a range.

You need to drag your formula across the range where you want the values of Sheet2 to be shown. And lock the range of Sheet2, like this:

```
=HLOOKUP(Sheet1!B3,'Sheet2'!$H$2:$I$3,2,FALSE)
```

Then copy or drag the formula to the right or down, depending on if the values in Sheet1 are in B3, C3, D3, etc. (to the right) or B3, B4, B5, etc. (down).